Duda sobre programita de C++ "Pruebas códigos de escape"
Quisiera saber por qué este programita de C++ no emite ningún pitido. Lo había compilado con Cxxdroid en un móvil Android. A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano:
// Programa: Pruebas de códigos de escape
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() 
{ 
   char alarma = '\a'; // alarma  
   char bs = '\b'; // retroceso de espacio 
   cout << alarma;
   cout << bs;
   return 0;
}


¿Sistema operativo y terminal? Que eso funcione o no (que haga "beep") depende en ultima instancia de la terminal usada. '\a' representa el carácter ASCII BEL, el como la terminal responda al mismo cuando se imprime en la salida estándar ya no depende de C++.

Gracias por tu respuesta es que lo he compilado en un móvil android.

Hola Martín, deberías colocar en tu pregunta, lo que aquí manifiestas.

Vale gracias editaré la pregunta.

Si no funciona es porque la terminal no lo soporta. Pruébalo en otra
